# Opacity doesn't work in IE?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, opacity

On my demo page - [(click here)](http://www.ioterm.com) when it displays in IE 11, (this `HTML` tag below should be not visible, it works at least for other browsers, for example, FF, Chrome, Yandex) but somehow it is displaying at the left side. I tried a lot but couldn't find any workaround to fix this situation.

```
<a href="#" class="close"></a>
```

**Here is my sample HTML:**

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if IE 6 ]><html lang="en-us" class="ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]><html lang="en-us" class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html lang="en-us" class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 7)|!(IE)]><!-->
<html lang="en-US" class="no-js">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <!-- ==============================================
       Title and basic Meta Tags
       =============================================== -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>IOTERM Connected Intelligence</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="ioterm">
    <meta name="keywords" content="IOTERM,IOT,Sensors,Device,Connected">

    <!-- ==============================================
       Mobile Metas
       =============================================== -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <!-- ==============================================
       Google Fonts
       =============================================== -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:700,400,500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- ==============================================
       CSS
       =============================================== -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <!-- ==============================================
      Google Analytics
      =============================================== -->

    <script>
      (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
      })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

      ga('create', 'UA-70078154-1', 'auto');
      ga('send', 'pageview');


    </script>
    <!-- ==============================================
       Multi Language Pack
       =============================================== -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/js.cookie.js" charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-lang.js" charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/langpack/nonDynamic.js" charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.velocity.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.kenburnsy.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/init.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Create language switcher instance and set default language to en
        var lang = new Lang('tr');

    </script>
</head>
<body class="preload">

    <!-- Overlay -->
    <div id="firefly" class="bg-overlay">
        <canvas id="star-canvas"></canvas>

    </div>
    <!-- End Overlay -->
    <div class="lang">
        <a href="#turkish" onclick="window.lang.change('tr'); return false;"><img src="images/turkey-icon.png" alt="Türkçe" ></a>
        <a href="#english" onclick="window.lang.change('en'); return false;"><img src="images/uk-icon.png" alt="English" ></a>

    </div>
    <!-- Header -->
    <header>

        <div class="intro">

            <!-- Site Logo -->
            <div class="logo"></div>
            <!-- End Site Logo -->
            <!-- Rotator Title -->
            <div id="rotate">
                <h1 class="rotate" lang="tr">BİZ <span lang="tr">NESNELERİN İNTERNETİ (IOT)</span><br>ÇÖZÜMLERİ <br>ŞİRKETİYİZ, <span lang="tr">BİZ IOTERM'ÜZ</span></h1>

                <h1 class="rotate" lang="tr">DAHA İYİ <br><span lang="tr">BİR DÜNYA İÇİN</span> <br lang="tr">BÜTÜNLEŞİK BİLGİ <span lang="tr">SAĞLIYORUZ.</span></h1>
            </div>
            <!-- End Rotator Title -->

            <p lang="tr">ÇOK YAKINDA</p>
            <p><span></span><i class="fa fa-hourglass-half"></i><span></span></p>
            <p lang="tr">GELİYORUZ</p>

        </div>
        <!-- Nav -->
        <nav>
            <ul class="navigation">

                <li class="link center bottom move"><a href="#contact" title="Contact"><span lang="tr">İLETİŞİM</span></a></li>

            </ul>
        </nav>
        <!-- End Nav -->
    </header>
    <!-- End Header -->

    <!-- Contact Section -->
    <section id="contact" data-direction="from-right">
        <div class="container fill">
            <h1>
                <span lang="tr">İLETİŞİM</span>
            </h1>
            <!-- ./End Section Title -->
            <a href="#" class="close"></a>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <h4 lang="tr">BİZE E-POSTA GÖNDEREBİLİR VEYA AŞAĞIDAKİ FORMU DOLDURABİLSİNİZ. SİZE EN KISA SÜREDE GERİ DÖNÜŞ YAPACAĞIZ.</h4>
                    <!-- Begin Phone -->
                    <div class="newline col-sm-3 text-center">
                        <i class="fa fa-mobile fa-2x"></i>
                        <br>
                        +90 (530) 1407342
                    </div>
                    <!-- End Phone -->
                    <!-- Begin Email -->
                    <div class="newline col-sm-3 text-center">
                        <i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-2x"></i>
                        <br>
                        contact@ioterm.com
                    </div>
                    <!-- End Email -->
                    <!-- Begin Address -->
                    <div class="newline col-sm-3 text-center">
                        <i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i>
                        <br>
                        IOTERM
                        <br>
                        İstanbul, <span lang="tr">Türkiye</span>.
                    </div>
                    <!-- End Address -->
                    <!-- Begin Address -->
                    <div class="newline col-sm-3 text-center">
                        <i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i>
                        <br>
                        IOTERM
                        <br>
                        Boston, <span lang="tr">ABD</span>.
</div>
                    <!-- End Address -->
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    <div class="contactForm">
                        <!-- Start Contact Form -->
                        <form id="contactForm" action="#" method="post" role="form">

                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input id="formName" type="text" class="input required" name="name" placeholder="Adınız" lang="tr">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input id="formEmail" type="email" class="input required" name="email" placeholder="E-posta adresiniz" lang="tr">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input id="phone" type="text" placeholder="Telefon numaranız" value="" size="30" name="phone" lang="tr">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <textarea id="message" class="textarea required" name="message" rows="3" cols="40" placeholder="Sorunuz" lang="tr"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <button value="Submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-green-border btn-lg" type="submit" lang="tr">GÖNDER</button>
                            </div>

                        </form>
                        <div class="successMsg"></div>
                        <!-- End Contact Form -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- End Contact Section -->


</body>
</html>
```

**Here is the relevant portion of CSS:**

```
/*======================== SECTIONS ========================*/
section {
    font: 1em/1.5em "Raleway", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: rgba(120,184,195,0.6);
    z-index: -99999;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.container {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
#about .content, #solutions .container, #contact .container {
    opacity: 0;
}

#about.active .content, #solutions.active .container, #contact.active .container {
    opacity: 1;
}
.intro {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.intro h1 {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 70px;
    line-height: 1.1;
    letter-spacing: -2px;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    width: 100%;
}
.intro h1 span {
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #48C0F4;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
}
.intro p {
    font-size: 18px;
    letter-spacing: 0.4em;
    margin: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.intro p span {
    border-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-right: 0 none;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px 0px 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 6px 10px;
    width: 100px;
}
.intro i {
    color: #48C0F4;
}
section h1 {
    font-size: 70px;
    line-height: 1.1;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin: 80px 0px 40px 0px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    color: #FFF;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
}

section h1 span {
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 700;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #48C0F4;
    padding-bottom: 0.15em;
}

.newline {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#about, #contact, #solutions {
    background: rgba(15,52,107,0.6);

}
#about.active, #contact.active, #solutions.active {
    background: rgba(58, 115, 107,0.6);
}
/*======================== CLOSE BUTTON  ========================*/
.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 5%;
    display: block;
    width: 58px;
    height: 58px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    margin-top: -30px;
    margin-left: -30px;
    background: url('../images/close.png') no-repeat center center;
    border: 2px solid #ffffff;
    border-radius: 100%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
}
#contact .close {
    top: 7%;
    left: 50%;

}
#solutions .close {
    right: 5%;
}
#about .close {
    left: 5%;
}
.close:hover, .close:hover:before, .close:hover:after {
    opacity: 0.9;
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.contactForm {
    padding-top: 40px;
}
#contact i {
    background: rgba(72,192,244,0.9);
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 24px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    margin-left: 3px;
    padding-top: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out 0s;
    -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out 0s;
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: all 300ms ease-in-out 0s;
}
.form-group{
margin-bottom:0px;
}

/*======================== ANIMATION ========================*/
a, .close:before, .close:after {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in;
    transition: all 1s ease-in;
}
section {
    -webkit-transition: background 1s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: background 1s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: background 1s ease-in;
    -o-transition: background 1s ease-in;
    transition: background 1s ease-in;
}

/*======================== RESPONSIVE ========================*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 1123px) {
h1, .intro h1 {
    font-size: 58px;
}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
h1, .intro h1 {
    font-size: 48px;
}
.navigation .link.left {
    left: 30px;
}
.navigation .link.right {
    right: 30px;
}
.close {
    top: 50%;
    right: 4%;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: -25px;
    margin-left: -25px;
}
#contact .close {

    top: 92%;
    left: 50%;
}
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
.intro h1 {
padding:0px 85px;
}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
html, body {
    overflow-y: auto !important;
}
body {
    height: auto !important;
}
header {
    position: relative !important;
    top: auto !important;
    left: auto !important;
    right: auto !important;
    bottom: auto !important;
    min-height: 550px;
}
.intro h1 {
    font-size: 40px;
}
.intro p{
font-size:16px;
}
.intro p span {
width:80px;
}
section {
    position: relative !important;
    top: auto !important;
    left: auto !important;
    right: auto !important;
    bottom: auto !important;
    z-index: 2 !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
section .content, section .container {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
.navigation {
    display: none;
}
section {
    padding: 4em 0;
}
#solutions {
    padding: 0;
}
#solutions h1 {
    background: none !important;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0px !important;
}
.close {
    display: none;
}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
body {
    font-size: 14px;
    border: 0px solid transparent;
}
h1, .intro h1 {
    font-size: 32px;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 28px;
}
h3 {
    font-size: 24px;
}
h4 {
    font-size: 20px;
}
.intro p{
font-size:14px;
}
.intro p span {
width:60px;
}
section h1 {
    font-size: 2.5em;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
}
.lang {
    position: relative !important;
    margin-top: 0.7em !important;
    margin-right: 0.7em !important;
    float:right;
    z-index: +5;

}
```

Help please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your container is the one who is setting the opacity of all content inside it. 
So your `.container` should be relative, so try to add the `position` to `relative` and see how it behaves.

```
#about .container, #subscribe .content, #contact .container {
    opacity: 0;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work @Elow. First of all this CSS works for Chrome, FF etc so there has to be something else. By the way, if I change opacity to 0 as you suggested the close tag completely dissapears. What I would like to do is to set it hidden at the first page load for IE and when the navigation link pressed at the bottom of the page this close tag will appear.

Comment: It seems relative did the trick but this time the position of the close tags breaks down. Should I add relative to those? `#contact .close {
 top: 7%;
    left: 50%;

}
#solutions .close {
 right: 5%;
}
#about .close {
 left: 5%;
}`

Comment: I think `#solutions .close {
 right: 5%;
    position: fixed;
}
#about .close {
 left: 5%;
    position: fixed;
}` will work!

Answer (score 0):

If you set your element which is applying the opacity: 0 to position: relative that may fixes the issue.

I guess, IE 11 works somehow different. Your closing-element is set to position: absolute. But it is not in relation to the element set to opacity: 0 but to the parent of that element.

Comment: Hi @Sven, thanks for your reply, position relative fixed the issue but this time position of the close tag breaks down. Please check my comment to Elow's answer.

Comment: Hi, just checked once again and is there a reason why initial the element 'id-'contact' got left: 0 and after visiting (closed) left 100%?

Comment: where did u get that @Sven?

Comment: Before interaction: <section id="contact" data-direction="from-right">
After interaction after closed: <section id="contact" data-direction="from-right" style="left: 100%; z-index: -99999;" class="">

you may just show the .close if the parent got the class="active" that fixes the issue too.